# Place ACF graphs of 2 variables side by side

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, time-series, autocorrelation

I am plotting the ACF graphs of two time series called *unrate* and *epop* in a dataframe called *labor*. Here is the code:

```
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 8,4

for variable in labor.columns:
    plot_acf(labor[variable], lags = 20, title = 'ACF of ' + variable)
```

But this results in the 2 graphs one below the other (in 2 rows, 1 column). I would like the 2 graphs to be placed side by side in 1 row only (1 row and 2 columns). What adjustments should I make to the code?

Comment: are u looking for `plt.subplot()` ?

Comment: i think so. I mean, if it works.